# JavaScript, как по очереди отобразить картинки из массива в div?

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть массив с картинок:

```
var slide = new Array();
slide[0] = new Image();
slide[0].src = "photo0";
slide[1] = new Image();
slide[1].src = "photo1";
```

И вот так я пыталась отобразить его на странице:

```
 <img name="myImg"> 
 document.images["myImg"].src = slide[0].src;
```

Но отображается белый квадрат, разорванный по середине. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так?

Comment: А вы понимаете, что вы сами пишите? Знаете что значит `new Image();`  например? Или например скажите почему наличие строки `photo0` в атрибуте `src` должно отображать картинку?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, насчет new Image() - как я понимаю, это почти как с файлами в Php. Переменной присваивается это new Image(), возможно с шириной и высотой, а потом в виде var photo.src = "Here is path" добавляется картинка. Но в том то и дело, что я не могу понять как её показать, каким способом. Потому и задала вопрос

Comment: `Переменной присваивается это new Image(),` - что конкретно происходит при `new Image()` вы не знаете? потому что судя по записи `document.images["myImg"].src = slide[0].src;`  определенно не знаете. Хотя где-то же прочитали про new Image()........`а потом в виде var photo.src = "Here is path" добавляется картинка.`  - нуууу допустим...так, и куда ведет ваш `photo0` ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, Image() - конструктор, как я знаю. Но да, Вы правы, я не совсем знаю, как им пользоваться

Comment: `new  Image()` создает новый DOM элемент. Если конкретно, то картинку. Если вы вобъете эту конструкцию в консоль то увидите `<img>`. Отсюда первый шаг и вопрос: в итоге вы хотите в уже созданный элемент `<img name="myImg">` вставить путь до картинки? тогда манипуляции с new Image() излишни........... или всё же создавать динамически? тогда `<img name="myImg">` совершенно тут не нужен

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, поняла. Но slide[0].src = "photo0" содержит только путь к картинке. Тогда как же отобразить его как картинку? Его же надо куда-то вставить, верно?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67424/discussion-between--and--).